# How does these template specializations with function signature like arguments work?

Tags: c++, templates

Having read quite a few articles about templates, template specializations, and partial specializations, I still cannot understand how and why the following template witchcraft works.

```
template <class T> class Signal;
template <class Arg, class Ret>
class Signal<Ret (Arg)> {
  typedef std::function<Ret (Arg)> Callback;
};

int main() {
  Signal<void (int x)> signal;
}
```

I have a rather good idea of what the code does and how to utilize it, I just cannot understand why and how. How does the compiler interpret specialization parameters holding spaces and parentheses, like `class Signal<Ret (Arg)>`? How/why does `void (int x)` match the specialization `class Signal<Ret (Arg)>`? And why is the `template <class Arg, class Ret>` even necessary? Why not just use `<>` as in "normal" specializations? The order of `class Arg` and `class Ret` doesn't seem to matter, why?

I'm sorry if these questions doesn't make any sense. If they don't, don't bother answering them directly. I just want to understand how and why the above code works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that `void(int x)` is a single type, namely the type of the function taking `int` and returning `void` (parameter name `x` is ignored here) and this type is bound to `T` in the `Signal`. But there is a specialization for this case, so it gets chosen and `Ret` is bound to `void` and `Arg` to `int`. The order doesn't matter *in the template aragument list*, it does however matter where you use them in the specialised arguments, for passed arguments will be bound to different things that way.

The same thing is also possible for array types:

```
template <typename T>
struct C;

template <typename Element, std::size_t size>
struct C<Еlement[size]> {};

int main() {
    C<int[42]> c;
}
```

What you call *"normal" specializations* are actually named *full specialisations* as they don't require additional parameters to be supplied to form a type, hence the empty template argument list. Your example and the one above are called *partial specializations* and can be used for other templates as well:

```
template <typename T, int size>
struct Array {};

template <typename Element, std::size_t size>
struct C<Array<Еlement, size>> {};

int demo() {
    C<Array<int, 10>> a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A definition of a template having a single template parameter:

```
template <class T> class Signal;
```

Specialize the template with a function having a return value (or void) and an argument:

```
template <class R, class A>
class Signal<R (A)> {
  typedef std::function<R (A)> Callback;
};
```

Specialize the template with a function having a return value (or void) and two arguments:

```
template <class R, class A0, class A1>
class Signal<R (A0, A1)> {
  typedef std::function<R (A0, A1)> Callback;
};
```

And so on ...

Even each specialization is a template with multiple parameters, it refers to a single pattern of a function signature.
A "normal" specialization can not describe a set of function signatures, but a single one:

```
template <>
class Signal<void (int)> {
  typedef std::function<void (int)> Callback;
};
```

Note: Only the order of template parameters in the specialization (eg.: Signal< R (A) >) is relevant.